# Java: Cut array into nth number then add to database

Tags: java, arrays, oracle

I want to cut array into nth number and add to database

Sample:
array = {John,Doe,sampleFirstName,SampleLastName,Fname,Lname}
DB table = fname varchar(20), lname varchar (20)

loop the first two, then insert to db table? is it possible?

```
for(int x=0;x>array.size();x++){
    insertToDb("John", "Doe"); 
    insertToDb("sampleFirstName", "SampleLastName"); //something like this to add to DB
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could loop over pairs of elements:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length / 2; i += 2) {
    insertToDB(array[i], array[i + 1];
}
```

Comment: It's not common thing nor a standard but I prefer to use two loop driver variables, rather than just `i` :)
`(int i = 0, j = i + 1; j < array.length; i += 2, j = i + 1)`

Comment: normally, I used 2d arrays for this, but this time am not sure on the size of array so I used simple array. let me try your inputs :) thanks!